# Sample grammars in FParsec going beyond the samples?

Tags: parsing, f#, parsec, fparsec

I am looking for some sample grammars written in FParsec that would go beyond the samples in the project repository.

I have found this very nice [grammar of GLSL](http://laurent.le-brun.eu/site/index.php/2010/06/07/54-fsharp-and-fparsec-a-glsl-parser-example), but this is the only sample I found. What I need is a grammar for a language similar to C or JavaScript.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Luca Bolognese has written a great series of *[Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours in F#](http://lucabolognese.wordpress.com/2011/06/30/write-yourself-a-scheme-in-48-hours-in-f-part-i/)* where he used FParsec for parsing. The full source code with detailed test cases are online [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Write-Yourself-a-Scheme-in-d50ae449/sourcecode?fileId=24192&pathId=495493601).

The most relevant post is [6th one](http://lucabolognese.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/write-yourself-a-scheme-in-48-hours-in-f-part-vi/) where he talked about parsing a simple Lisp-like language. This language is closer to JavaScript than to C just so you know.

Current series on his blog is *[parsing lambda expressions in F#](http://lucabolognese.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/adventure-in-parserland-parsing-lambda-expressions-in-f-part-i/)* (using FParsec) which could be helpful for you too.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/iigorr/pgn.net) is an implementation of a parser for the [Portable Game Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation) (PGN, a file format for chess games) in F# using FParsec, called [pgn.net](https://github.com/iigorr/pgn.net)

The PGN format is easy to understand, so the use cases are quite clear. There are many variations of the format (e.g. what a move is) so there many small examples.